# Why AOT compilation isn't default way of building Angular2 applications?

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

When performance improvements, bundle size improvements and tree shaking advantages are significant for not so complex apps with AOT, why AOT is not recommended way for building and deploying angular apps?

There are some discussions about its limitations when application size is huge, but not that convincing to not use it as default.